# Switching to GetSingleItem instead of findItemsAdvanced with the ebay-api

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I am using the ebay-api's to pull out listing information using the itemId the user enters to import the current live auction on ebay into my site. I have been using the FindItemsAdvanced which is pretty straight forward grabbing the information using the SingleXMLElement

```
        $itemid = (string) $xml->searchResult->item->itemId;
        $shipcost = (string) $xml->searchResult->item->shippingInfo->shippingServiceCost;
```

I dont really need to use the FindItemsAdvanced because some information is missing, ie: quantity of a item listed.

I have looked at the documentation for GetSingleItem and it doesnt have a searchResult member, my question is, how is the above done with GetSingleItem to get the details.

This is the process i used but cant grab any details

```
url2 is - http://open.api.ebay.com/shopping?callname=GetSingleItem&responseencoding=XML&appid=myIdApp&siteid=0&version=967&ItemID=192401461174&IncludeSelector=Details
```

then the contents

```
$resp2 = file_get_contents($url2);
```

then the xml object

```
$xml2 = new SimpleXMLElement($resp2);
```

At this stage i have my object but i cant extract any details like a can with FindItemsAdvanced

Thanks to the comments i'm adding more information, the file_get_contents only gives me this

```
2017-12-24T12:33:55.736Z Success E1033_CORE_APILW_18542200_R1 1033 false 192401461174 2018-01-17T10:29:17.000Z 2017-12-18T10:29:17.000Z http://www.ebay.com/itm/Aspire-CF-SUB-OHM-Mod-Battery-Ecig-Vape-Kit-Carbon-Fibre-Aspire-k3-Samsung-25r-/192401461174 FixedPriceItem wigan, Lancashire PayPal http://thumbs3.ebaystatic.com/pict/1924014611748080_1.jpg https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTQ1WDczMQ==/z/6PkAAOSwttFaD~0~/$_1.PNG?set_id=8800005007 https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NzIwWDI5MA==/z/kccAAOSwtGlZCa0C/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/OTAyWDYwMA==/z/Gk8AAOSw42JZCa0D/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/Nzg3WDExODE=/z/eNkAAOSwQcJaBAo8/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/OTAwWDkwMA==/z/zQgAAOSwyP5aD~1K/$_1.JPG?set_id=8800005007 https://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NTAwWDUwMA==/z/6RIAAOSwttFaD~1L/$_1.PNG?set_id=8800005007 wn69jt 183498 Health & Beauty:E Cigarettes, Vapes & Accs:E Cigarettes, Vapes & Mods 5 improveyourlife Purple 525 100.0  0 31.94 23.9 Active 0 Worldwide UK P23DT21H55M22S  184 26395:183497:183498 GB 14 days Returns Accepted Only if broken Buyer  false false 0 1000 New false 0 false true true
```

I understand i need to get the xml into a string to use namespaces but i'm not sure how to do that. The crazy thing is, the only thing i need out of GetSingleItem is the quantity because FindItemsAdvanced does not have it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$xml2 = simplexml_load_string($resp2);` and then you should be able to get the information needed normally, with `$quantity = $xml2->Item->Quantity;`.

As a tip, I highly recommend you give a try to [this SDK](http://devbay.net/). I am using it for a long time, to manage multiple shops and it's extremely helpful. Saved me a huge amount of time. The guy who created it also made a ton of [examples](https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-examples). You could have a look at those before using the SDK, and you'll see how much simpler everything is.